# Sinon: Stubbing static method of class does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, class, testing, static, sinon

I want to mock the following class, that is used as dependency for another one:

```
module.exports = class ResponseHandler {

static response(res, status_, data_, codes_) {
    console.log('Im here. Unwillingly');
    // doing stuff here...
};
```

The ResponseHandler is imported by the ProfileController and used there:

```
const response = require('../functions/tools/response.js').response;

module.exports = class ProfileController {

static async activateAccountByVerificationCode(req, res) {
    try{
        // doing stuff here
        return response(res, status.ERROR, null, errorCodes);
    }
}
```

Now I'm writing Unit Tests for the ProfileController and there I'm testing if **activateAccountByVerificationCode** calls **response** with the given arguments

```
describe('ProfileController', () => {

    let responseStub;

    beforeEach(function() {

        responseStub = sinon.stub(ResponseHandler, 'response').callsFake(() => null);
    });
```

But despite the fact that **response** is mocked, the ProfileController still calls the real implementation of response (See console output: *'Im here. Unwillingly'*)

```
    it('should respond accordingly if real verification code does not fit with the one passed by the user', async function () {
        // here you can still see that real implementation is still called
        // because of console output 'I'm here unwillingly'
        await controller.activateAccountByVerificationCode(req, res);

        console.log(responseStub.called); // -> false
        expect(responseStub.calledWith(res, status.ERROR, null, [codes.INVALID_VERIFICATION_CODE])).to.eql(true); // -> negative
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock you controllers dependecies with a library like [`proxyquire`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) first and then use this mocked instance in you test. Otherwise you will still use the original (unstubbed) implementation.

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('ProfileController', () => {

    let responseStub;
    let Controller;

    beforeEach(function() {

        responseStub = sinon.stub(ResponseHandler, 'response').callsFake(() => null);
        Controller = proxyquire('./ProfileController', {'../functions/tools/response':responseStub})
    });

    it('should respond accordingly if real verification code does not fit with the one passed by the user', async function () {
        // here you can still see that real implementation is still called
        // because of console output 'I'm here unwillingly'
        await Controller.activateAccountByVerificationCode(req, res);

        console.log(responseStub.called); // -> false
        expect(responseStub.calledWith(res, status.ERROR, null, [codes.INVALID_VERIFICATION_CODE])).to.eql(true); // -> negative
    });
```

`Controller` then uses your stubbed version of the function and can be inspected.